# How to fix scroll button to always go down to next section unless last section go back to top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a section hopper button on my page that works almost like I want. Right now it's going to the next section but based on the documents page flow of "sections" so if a user scrolls down without the button and then they click the button it goes back up to the "next section" of the page and not the actual next "section". I'm trying to find a way that no matter where they are if they click the button it goes to the actual next section unless they hit the bottom section which in that case it scrolls back to top, which I currently have working. Any advice would be awesome! thanks!

I have it going to the next section based on .next() but it is still going to the next section on the page and not the actual next section depending where the user is located on the page. Each section I want to go to next has a class of .bucket-section

HTML:

```
 <div class="scroll-indicator__container">
    <div class="scroll-indicator">
    Scroll Button
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
var scrollButton = $('.scroll-indicator')
var currentPosition = $bucketSections.first()


//scroll indicator, scroll to closest section
  $(scrollButton).click(function () {
    var currentPosition = $currentPosition.next('.bucket-section');

    if (currentPosition.length) {
        $currentPosition = currentPosition;

    } else {
        $currentPosition = currentPosition = $('.bucket-section').first();
    }

    $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
        scrollTop: $(currentPosition).offset().top - 50,
    }, 800);
    return false;
});


 //rotate arrow to point up when reaches last section
$window.scroll(function () {
    var scrollIndicatorHeight = $(document).height() - $window.height() - $window.scrollTop();

    if (scrollIndicatorHeight <= $('.section--registration-form').height()) {
        $(scrollButton).addClass('scroll-indicator--up');
    } else {
        $(scrollButton).removeClass('scroll-indicator--up');
    }
});
```

click button go the next section no matter where user is on page, if possible